# Laravel : Getting URL parameters again in query parameters

Tags: php, laravel, url, lumen

**I am getting all URL parameters again as query string parameters in URL.**

> Example :-

**I am requesting this URL:**
http://www.example.com/v4/def?param1=value1&param2=value2

**But I am getting below:**
http://www.example.com/v4/def?%2Fv4%2Fdef=&param1=value1&param2=value2

I am using `Request::fullUrl()` to get full URL.

Someone could help me for above scenario

Thanks

Comment: How to get the URL parameter? Please explain and put your code for more investigate your issue.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I have update my question.

Comment: I have tested the above URL  using  `Request::fullUrl()` working fine. 
Now the question is where you have used the generated URL. Like in blade view or other.

Comment: Put some code on how you have getting and using this URL. Like controller or blade file

Comment: I am using above code in controller, but I think it's doesn't matter where I am using this. I am getting same URL in both the cases.

Comment: But generated URL some time not render correctly on the browser. So You should render on blade file and `inspect(F12)` Html so that you can see URL is proper or not.

Comment: return URL from the controller and render it on the blade view.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller file:

```
$url = Request::fullUrl();
return view('your view file', compact('url'));
```

In blade view file:

```
{{ $url }}
```